# Payload bytes different from actual bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, byte, corruption

I've got a problem where when the user sends image data, it's saved on the server corrupt.

So, I essentially have this setup:

```
- api
  . index.js
  - methods
    . users.js
```

(I've cut out files that are unrelated to the problem)

Outside of the API file, there is a `server.js` which initaites it whenever api.example.com is visisted.  (Basically like a VirtualHost)

---

That being said.  Here is the problem:

**`./api/index.js`** (Points of problem)

```js
// All this essentiall does is get the get the whole payload as a buffer.
req.on("data", function(chunk){
  // Potential problem area.
  req.api.payload = ((req.api.payload) ? (Buffer.concat([req.api.payload, chunk])) : (chunk));
});
```

```js
req.on("end", function(){
  // Check if we're on api.example.com/users/
  if (path[0].match(/^users$/i)) {
    methods.users(req, res);
  }
});
```

I think the issue is somewhere when the payload.

But...  Just incase, I'll include the `./api/methods/users.js`...  (Only including parts where the problem could arise, since it's a big file)

**`./api/methods/users.js`**

```
else if (req.method.match(/^POST$/i)) {

  if (!path[2] || path[2].match(/^(?:info|data)$/i)) {
    // ... (Everything that was here didn't apply to the image upload)
  } else if (path[2].match(/^(?:pic|picture|avatar)$/i)) {
    // Url matches api.example.com/users/<user_id>/pic

    var __base = "/home/user/web/hosts/resources/static/images/api/users/"; // Upload path

    // Another potential spot where the problem could be.
    fs.writeFile(__base + path[1] + ".png", req.api.payload, "binary",  function(err){
      if (err) res.api.end(err);
      res.api.end(req.api.payload.slice(0, 40)); // Testing
    });
  }

}
```

Note that this is just for testing the uploading, I realize someone could upload other data, but this is local.  It's simply for testing the uploaded data, for now.

Another note, any variable that you don't see explicitly defined is not related to the problem, just no that:

- `path`: Url as array e.g. `"/user/xero/info"` -> `["user", "xero", "info"]`
- `req.api`: A object created before hand (in the main `server.js` file).

One more note, I'm uploading the file via a cURL command:

```
curl -X POST -d @random.png http://api.poweredrails.org/users/test4/pic
```

Comment: It does work, the files saves.  It's just that it's saved corrupt.

Comment: Where is `payload` defined?

Comment: ok, got it path[1]=<userId>, path[2]=pic...the (2nd) payload variable in req.on("data): What scope does it have? How is it initialized? What is the state (after any request)?

Comment: @mscdex and xerx593 Sorry, that was a post error. See edit.

Comment: Did you try adding something like `req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/data.debug'))` before/after you add your `req` event handlers so you get the exact raw data? If the data in that temporary file is not right, then there is something wrong on the client end...

Comment: and another (maybe stupid) question, but: Why do you slice the payload (in the callback of writeFile ..I see //Testing comment, but it could also be "it")?

Comment: @xerx593, That was just to see how the bytes differed.  The values would be showed in the response, and I would then compare them to the actual file's bytes.  They're different.

Comment: @mscdex, I just tried it, and the image is still corrupt...  Perhaps it's cURL?

Comment: It's not being sent gzipped, is it?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I wouldn't think so, does cURL Gzip the data unless specified not to?

Comment: @JamenMarz: I personally have no idea, just a guess at the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `curl` usage, you need to specify `--data-binary` instead of just `-d`. You should also set a `Content-Type` header so that curl will do the right thing:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: image/png" --data-binary @random.png http://api.poweredrails.org/users/test4/pic
```

Another option is to support the use of multipart/form-data in your backend app, especially if want to submit other information with the image. Then your curl usage would look like:

```
curl -X POST --form "mypicture=@random.png" --form "foo=bar" http://api.poweredrails.org/users/test4/pic
```